# How to update the column and clear cache from datatable jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using fnUpdate to update the columns,it is updating the columns correctly but when i insert new row and try to update column of the pirticular row, it is updating the different rows.

Here is the code

```
    $('#example').dataTable().fnUpdate("value", rowindex,
                        columnindex);
```